# summing records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table of records like

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ PID ║ NAME ║  DATE1   ║  DATE2   ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 123 ║ john ║ 20110401 ║ 19700101 ║
║ 123 ║ john ║ 20110401 ║ 19700101 ║
║ 123 ║ john ║ 20110401 ║ 19700101 ║
║ 323 ║ mike ║ 20110401 ║ 19900101 ║
║ 323 ║ mike ║ 20110401 ║ 19900101 ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

`query1` is `count` on `pid`

`query2` is if all the four fields are same the record is to be taken as one record else individual records and records to be counted on `pid` order.

The above result is:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PID ║ TOTALRECORDS ║ TOTALUNIQUE ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 123 ║            3 ║           1 ║
║ 323 ║            2 ║           1 ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I did `select pid,count(pid),(select count(pid) group by pid,name,date1,date2) from <table> group by pid;`

But I get an error... kindly correct my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  pid,
        COUNT(*) totalRecords,
        COUNT(DISTINCT name, date1, date2) totalUnique
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY pid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4127c5/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with not unique record*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77386b/1)

Result

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PID ║ TOTALRECORDS ║ TOTALUNIQUE ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 123 ║            3 ║           1 ║
║ 323 ║            2 ║           1 ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```